# Android how to use KSoap for sending a huge data

Tags: android, ksoap2

Is there any way to send a huge data encoded to a 64-based String? It throws a 'outofmemory' exception when converting the data to string.

Cheers,
Stone

Comment: Why do you have to convert the data into a string? Would ´t it be better if you use the Base64.OutputStream / Base64.InputStream?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you got beyond memory borders even before ksoap got involved.  Your data is just too  freaking big when converted into base64 string.  if you can not reduce amount of data tranfered,   you shall switch to some streaming technique - like writing base64 data to stream / socked without allocating string.  Or slice up your data in manageable pieces. 
Or rethink your service architecture

Comment: Yes, I know in my case I have to split the data into smaller packets. Thanks everybody. I will try with Base64.Input/OutputStream